# Placing divs in the same row in desktop as reverse in responsive view

Tags: html, css, responsive

These div have a class of `col-sm-6` each in desktop view.

Say Div1 and Div2 are next to each other in same row.

But while viewing in responsive view especially in phones, the divs should be reversed. Div 2 and the Div 1 should be displayed in the same row.

How to achieve this.

```html
<div class="containerDiv row row-no-gutters">

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-right col-xs-6"  id="div1"> --- This is DIV 1

    <div class="menu1" id="menu1" >
       Div 1 content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-right col-xs-6" id="div2">  --- This is DIV 2
    <div id="menu2" >
      Div 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use grids, heres a nice article about grids in css https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: I am very new to UI design, Thank you for sharing this. Just a question if I give display: grid to the container grid and for Div 1 and Div2 as display: inline-grid, how will I reverse it in mobile view ?

Comment: This class does not `col-xs-`, I guess you meant `col-xs-6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw you were using BS classes in your html.

So you can use classes `order-` that are made for it. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#order-classes

This just based on css property: `order`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

### DEMO:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="containerDiv row row-no-gutters">

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-right col-xs-6 order-2 order-sm-1"  id="div1"> --- This is DIV 1

    <div class="menu1" id="menu1" >
         Div 1 content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-right col-xs-6 order-1 order-sm-2" id="div2">  --- This is DIV 2
    <div id="menu2" >
    Div 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try flex display. (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
// mobile display
.containerDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

// your desktop breakpoint here
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .containerDiv {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```